# Useless question?

Tags: discussion

I'm embarrassed to admit that I asked this horrible question: [Problems detecting android tablet IView 788TPC with mtp-tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463017/problems-detecting-android-tablet-iview-788tpc-with-mtp-tools)

At the time I was totally clueless about mtp AND ptp. The reason this question is so bad is that the model I asked about doesn't even offer mtp as a connection method. It received one answer that wasn't helpful (likely because the device doesn't support mtp). I attempted to answer the question myself indicating that fact, but my answer was subsequently deleted by a moderator. I think the question is useless but when I attempt to delete my question it warns me not to (due to the answer). Does anyone see any value in the aforementioned question whatsoever? I ask because I do not, but the system seems to think that it may have value.

Edit: requested image

[image: 788tpc]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the deleted answer for us lot that ain't mods (and don't have the 10k+ toolkit thing)? In the question think you could of included more details about the device, what happens in `dmesg` when you plug it, does `~/.mtpz-data` exist, version of mtp etc - it's not useless, just could be clearer with more detail. As there seems does not seem to be a clear question or answer, you could delete it if you want to.

Comment: (Continued :) It does seem to have been viewed 2064 times, so there could be a need for a clear Q&A about this (you can get stuff on other 'forums' ([e.g.](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1002004.html?sid=9b055af1b2f0ba390edfd5231fc9da8a)). Do you still need the question to be answered?

Comment: Ah, meta and upvotes. Do the upvotes mean that people think it is useless and should be deleted or does it mean it isn't useless? :D

Comment: @muru To the best of my knowledge, all the upvotes on a question means is that it's considered a good question by those who upvoted. Answers up indicate agreement and answers down indicate disagreement. Feel free to correct me where I'm wrong.

Comment: @ElderGeek that's how it's supposed to see, but I've often seen voting patterns that indicate otherwise. :D

Comment: @Wilf image added image. I believe the traffic to the question might be related to the popularity of the device during a sale by several of the online electronics outlets. As I now have a device that supports mtp it's clear that the Iview 788TPC device does not. Granted I had to make some changes to get the Iview i700 recognized by MTP, it was clearly designed to do so whereas the 788tpc was not. Thank yu for the offer of an answer, but I have an answer (see image above), it was deleted.

Comment: @Mitch why was it deleted? (might work... probably ended up in the low quality review queue or something)

Comment: @muru My theory is that systems work as well as they are understood by those using them.

Comment: @Wilf the point is that it can't work as the device doesn't offer it. I suppose if devices that support it weren't so cheap I could try a custom img. on it, but that would be off-topic regardless.

Comment: The point is moot. Voting to close the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is perfectly valid - at least from the point of view of asking.

There isn't a clear and valid reason why it should be deleted.  You obviously thought at the time there was a question about the device that needed an answer and then subsequently found the answer and self answered it.  BTW - I've undeleted your answer since I believe it is a genuine answer.

The question is useful, in that someone with the device could be looking for answers to that particular question - the answers there may be useful to that someone.

As to whether its on-topic or off-topic - no need for mod intervention here.  The community can & should vote appropriately.